# Rails/Slim auto-encoding Postgres geometric types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, slim-lang

I have Google Maps polygons stored as polygons in Postgres and I read them straight from DB to output to a react Component for editing using the Google Maps API.

In my local dev environment this works fine and by inspecting the data being fed to the React component everything looks normal:

```js
this.state = {
  map: "POLYGON ((10.69332405332034 59.88086121809927, 10.77572151425784 59.84569766552776, 10.81554695371096 59.84121336506844, 10.8450727105469 59.84518027707294, 10.86910530332034 59.85397478713949, 10.91442390683596 59.88499566305687, 11.020510637793 59.9383527020427, 10.99115654233401 59.96809210273585, 10.91811462644046 59.99462872670429, 10.80250068906253 60.0067306049673, 10.58723732236331 59.97273110496651, 10.43772026303714 59.86724837030302, 10.44239803555911 59.85643166134471, 10.44501587155..."
}
```

But in production it seems some kind of compression/encoding is taking effect, rendering the data unusable to Google Maps:

```js
this.state = {
  map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
}
```

**Background/environment**
We recently had to take a server out of service and in its place we added two new ones to the load balancer. They were set up through Cloud 66 using the same config so they should be exaclty the same, but I guess you never know.

We use slim syntax for templates.

I should clarify: Nothing is being done explicitly by our application code to the map field on its way from Postgres to the React component. We get the database record like so: `@coverage_map = CoverageMap.find(params[:id])` and then output it in the template like so: `coverageMap: @coverage_map`. The outputted data on display here is copied from the HTML template being rendered by Slim.

What could be happening here? Any tips on what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

In your dev environment you're retrieving the geometry from the database as `WKT` (Well Known Text), which is not PostgreSQL's standard output. In production you're getting a `WKB` (Well Known Binary) representation of the geometry, which is what you normally see when firing a simple select. What you need is to use [`ST_AsText`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) to get your `WKT`, e.g.

```
WITH mytable (geom) AS (
  VALUES ('POINT(1 1)'::geometry)
)
SELECT geom,ST_AsText(geom) FROM mytable;

                    geom                    | st_astext  
--------------------------------------------+------------
 0101000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F | POINT(1 1)
(1 Zeile)
```